# Why is my scatterplot not rotating?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, rotation

I am trying to create a 2d gaussian distribution and to rotate it by some degree.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.normal(0, 15, 5000)
y = np.random.normal(0, 3, 5000)

X = np.array([x, y])
print X.shape

angle = 28
theta = np.pi * angle / 180

rotation = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta),  np.cos(theta)]])
X1 = np.dot(rotation, X)
print X1.shape

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1).scatter(x, y)
fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2).scatter(X1[0], X1[:1])

plt.show()
```

What I expect to see here is a first scatterplot of gaussian and then the second one almost the same, but rotated by 28 degree. But instead I see this:

[image]

Comment: tom 's answer is correct.  If you are interested in other ways of plotting the bivariate distribution see https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/dan_patterson/2015/06/16/before-i-forget-8-bivariate-distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have an error in the way you index `X1`.

Currently, you plot `X1[0]` against `X1[:1]`, but `X1[:1]` is the same as `X1[0]`, as you are saying "all indices in the first dimension up to 1" (i.e. 0).

You just need to get rid of the colon - i.e. you need to plot `X1[0]` and `X1[1]`.

This works:

```
fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2).scatter(X1[0], X1[1])
```

[image]